# Why Does Java Stax Xml Parser Block

Tags: java, stax, jaxp

This works but next() function waits for 3-4 mins before parsing only a few lines. What's the reason?

```
XMLInputFactory xmlFact = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader xmlReader = xmlFact.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(tempFolder + "/" + "file.xml"));

while (xmlReader.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(xmlReader.getEventType());
    xmlReader.next();
}
```

It starts blocking after START_DOCUMENT

Xml Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE container PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
  <rootfiles xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
    <rootfile xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" full-path="123.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
  </rootfiles>
</container>
```

Comment: You should supply some more information as to which XML you are trying to pars and on which elements it stalls.

Comment: It starts waiting after START_DOCUMENT